# react-widgets: How to get Combobox name property value in onChange function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I read in react-widgets documentation :

```
name
type: string
The HTML name attribute, passed directly to the input element.
```

And I what to get the name property value in Combobox onChange function . So I wrote:

```
<Combobox
            data={featuredWeightList}
            valueField="id"
            textField="displayName"
            name="featuredWeight"
            defaultValue={featuredWeight}
            value={featuredWeight}
            onChange={this.handleFeaturedWeightChange}
          />

handleFeaturedWeightChange = (evt) => {
    const id = evt.id;
    const id = evt.displayName;
    // I do not have name property in evt variable 

  };
```

I do not have name property in evt variable, I got only "id" and "displayName" property.

But a normal html input, I can get directly name property in onChange function. Like this:

```
<Input
          type="text"
          name="address"
          value={door.address}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />

handleInputChange = (evt) => {
const target = evt.target;
const name = target.name;
console.log('Input value: ', value);
console.log('Input name: ', name);
};
```

Does someone have some suggestion about **How to get Combobox name property value in onChange function ?**

Thanks!

Comment: is there more than one property being sent in the callback from the combobox? you are only fetching the first (evt). It really depends on how the Combobox component is built. What it returns and so on. What repo is that coming from ?

Comment: @thsorens there is second property. But it's very strange that in the second property does not contain name property. Anyway thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this problem in this way (Hope it can help someone else):

```
  handleComboboxChange = (data, param) => {
    console.log(data, param);
    //Output: {id: 5, displayName: 5}  "featuredWeight"

  };

 <Combobox
   data={featuredWeightList}
   valueField="id"
   textField="displayName"
   name="featuredWeight"
   defaultValue={featuredWeight}
   value={featuredWeight}
   onChange={(param) => this.handleComboboxChange(param, 'featuredWeight')}
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible to use the javascript bind() function.

```
function a(name, evt) {
    console.log('name', name);
    console.log('evt', evt);
};

var b = a.bind(this, 'featuredWeight');
b({a: 'a', b: 'b'});
```

So it should look like:

```
<Combobox
            data={featuredWeightList}
            valueField="id"
            textField="displayName"
            name="featuredWeight"
            defaultValue={featuredWeight}
            value={featuredWeight}
            onChange={this.handleFeaturedWeightChange.bind(this, "featuredWeight")}
          />

handleFeaturedWeightChange = (name, evt) => {
    const id = evt.id;
    const id = evt.displayName;
    // I do not have name property in evt variable 
    console.log('name', name);
  };
```

Another way of doing this (without bind()):

```
function a(name) {
    return function(evt) {
      console.log('name', name)
    }
};

var b = a('featuredWeight');
b({a: 'a', b: 'b'});
```

Comment: `handleFeaturedWeightChange` function can be seen in the component. So I think it is not due to bind().

Comment: @b-bastien Thanks for the help. It should works, but according to ESLint: `JSX props should not use .bind()` . But if there is no better way to solve this problem, I will do like this. About the way without bind(). I Want to get the component name in onChange function so I can use the same handler to handle different components. So may be it will not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this variable to read the current selected value.
in onchange function write following line of code.

```js
 $('#RequestTypeId').change(function (e) {
        if ($(this).val() === "1") {
          //your code
          
        }
```